# How to find $\frac{dy}{dX}$ from the given equation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, logarithms

If y = $\ln \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\sqrt{1+X}-\sqrt{1-X}}{\sqrt{1+X}+\sqrt{1-X}}\end{pmatrix}$, how will you find $\frac{dy}{dX}$.[Edited]

- What does $\ln$ mean? (Sorry, I could'nt recall anything from differentiation)[Edit! But still could not solve.]
- How do you deal with fractions? Are there formulas I need. Please I need your help.

Comment: I hope it's $\ln$,( not $In$) the natural logarithm

Comment: I also think it would be ln, and you can use $ln(a/b)=ln(a)-ln(b)$ and don't have fractions.

Comment: I think you might have a typo in the fraction. The two terms in the numerator are equal, so the numerator is $0$ and the logarithm is everywhere undefined.

Comment: Specifically, I'd check the sign of all the terms. A question like $y=\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{1\color{red}{+}x}}{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1\color{red}{+}x}}\right)$ would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Try substituting X= cos(2k). It leads to more simplification i.e y= In(cot(pi/4 -2k))

Comment: @trula Sorry, I made the change now. Please check.

Comment: @Jam Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

(This is for the unedited version ...)

We have 
$$e^{2y}=\frac{1-x-\sqrt{1-x}}{1-x+\sqrt{1-x}}.$$
Now multiply numerator and denominator by ${1-x-\sqrt{1-x}}$, simplify  to
$$e^{2y}=1+2\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-1}{x}$$
and take the derivative
$$
e^{2y}\cdot2 y'=\left(1+2\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-1}{x}\right)'.
$$

Comment: While this is perfectly correct, I feel that implicitly differentiating both sides might be slightly more advanced than the asker's level. Implicit differentiation is usually covered later in syllabuses than the questions like the one they have asked. But of course if the asker feels comfortable with the method, it's up to them.

Answer (score 0):

First, we can multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}$, obtaining:
$$y=\ln(\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})^2)$$
Remembering the definition of the derivate of $\ln(x)$, we deduce:
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})^2}=\frac{2}{(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to approach the question is to use two theorems:

- $\displaystyle\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\ln(a)-\ln(b)$. This is one of the Laws of Logarithms, which you should be (or make yourself) familiar with.
- The chain rule: $\displaystyle (f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$. In words, the derivative of a composition can be reduced to a product of the derivative of the *outer* function and the derivative of the *inner* function. For example, the derivative of $\ln(\sqrt{x})$ would be $\displaystyle \underbrace{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}g}\ln (g)\right)}_{g=\sqrt{x}}\cdot \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sqrt{x}\right)=\left(\frac1g\right)\cdot\left(\frac12x^{-1/2}\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\frac12x^{-1/2}$.

This should give you all the tools you need to solve the question.

Comment: Would't it be easier to write $\ln(\sqrt{x})$ as $\frac12\ln(x)$ first?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Of course, but I was trying to give an easy example.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it first by multiplying the top and bottom by $\sqrt{1+X}+\sqrt{1-X}$:
$$y=\ln\frac{\sqrt{1+X}-\sqrt{1-X}}{\sqrt{1+X}+\sqrt{1-X}}=\ln\frac{1-\sqrt{1-X^2}}{X}=\\
\ln (1-\sqrt{1-X^2})-\ln X$$
Now take a derivative:
$$y'=\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{1-X^2}}\cdot \frac{X}{\sqrt{1-X^2}}-\frac1X$$
Can you simplify it?

Answer:

> $$y'=\frac{1}{X\cdot \sqrt{1-X^2}}$$

Answer (score -1):

$$\ln(x)=\log_e x$$

Just like any other logarithm, the natural logarithm is the power you need to raise $e$ to get $x$. Because the natural logarithm is so important, we often afford it its own notation (but you do see people write simply $\log x$, without specifying the base, to mean $\ln(x)$).

Michael Hoppe's answer seems to be the best approach for solving the question at hand. Note that he skipped out a middle step. After rewriting the problem as $e^y =$ ..., he squared both sides to give $e^{2y}$ on the LHS, eliminating all of the square root signs on the RHS.